# Shall I put that/when in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses, that, when

For your safety, you will only be given access to lifts and runs **that/when** your instructor determines you are capable of skiing safely.

I was wondering if we put "that", which is a relative clause used to define lifts and runs, the clause "you are capable of skiing safely" wound be weird.
Whereas the word "when" explains the "your instructor.." part, the main clause wouldn't explain what kind of lifts and runs "you" should use.

Comment: Since _ski_ can be transitive _lifts and runs that your instructor determines you are capable of skiing safely_ is grammatical; it means they determine you can ski the lifts and runs safely. It's still a relative clause, but _that_ refers to the lifts and runs, while _when_ refers to the time when they determine that you can ski (intransitive, no object, just skill level), not to any particular lifts and runs.